# How do I download the index.yaml file for a GAE app?

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I tried following the directions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code

The download does not include the index.yaml file. Anyone know how to force download of index.yaml using appcfg, or another method?

Comment: are you sure? I just checked the last source code I pulled down and index.yaml was created at the same time as the rest of the folder, so it looks like it pulled everything down, including the index definition.

Answer (score 2):

**By default the `index.yaml` file is not included in the application uploads. So if you have not modified the `skip_files` setting in you `app.yaml` file you will *not* be able to download the `index.yaml` file.**

Your can, however, customize the files that will be included by modifying the `skip_files` tag in your `app.yaml` file.
Something like this:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
- ^(.*/)?app\.yml
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*
- ^(.*/)?.*\.bak$
```

For more information on skip_files please read: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Skipping_Files

EDIT:

To be more clear. By default -- the `index.yaml` file is not included in the upload. The only way to download the `index.yaml` file would be to first make the change to your `app.yaml` file that I suggested. And, then, upload the app again. It is not possible to download a file that has not been uploaded.

Comment: BTW. If you've lost your app code and you're looking to reconstruct your entire app from the source download, and index.yaml isn't there, you could try to reconstruct it manually from the Indexes tab.

Comment: Kyle this is for upload, question is about downloading. You answer is misleading and should be deleted :P

Comment: @WooYek The reason that @user1601866 is not able to download the `index.yaml` is because--by default--it is not included in the upload. Therefore, the only way to download the `index.yaml` file would be to set `skip_files` in the `index.yaml` -- making certain not to include the `index.yaml` file. And then uploading the app again. Sorry I guess that could have been more clear. Does it make sense now?

Comment: …but then you must have the file in the first place. The question is obviously about the case when one don't not have the file any more. Your edit does clarify things a bit, but reading this longinsh answer is still waste of time, as most people getting here will not have access s to the original file.

Comment: @WooYek, I think that most people understand that if the file is not included in the upload they can *not* download it. Regardless I made it completely obvious now. Will you remove your down vote now?